# Multi-Value Prometheus Query Grafana

Tags: variables, kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, promql

I'm using Grafana plus Prometheus queries to create dashboards in Grafana for Kubernetes. I take the name of the nodes (3 in this case) in a variable and then I pass this values to other query to extract the IPs of the machines. The values extracted are correct. I have the multi-value option enabled.

The problem comes with the query `sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{id="/", instance=~"$ip_test:10250"}[1m]))` and more than one IP because it only takes one of them. In other query it works but I think it is possible because the other query has not the `:10250` after the variable.

My question, do you know any way to concatenate all the ip:port? E.g.: X.X.X.X:pppp|X.X.X.X:pppp

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total{id="/", instance=~"($ip_test):10250"}[1m]))
```

Answer (score 0):

From [multiple values formating](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/reference/templating/#formatting-multiple-values) documentation, Prometheus variables are expanded as [regex](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/reference/templating/#regex):

> InfluxDB and Prometheus uses regex expressions, so the same variable
>   would be interpolated as (host1|host2|host3). Every value would also
>   be regex escaped if not, a value with a regex control character would
>   break the regex expression.

Therefore your variable `ip_test = ['127.0.0.1', '127.0.0.2',...]` is supposed to be transformed into: `(127\.0\.0\.1|127\.0\.0\.2)`.

This means that your expression `=~$ip_test:10250` should be transformed into `=~"(127\.0\.0\.1|127\.0\.0\.2):10250"` so you don't need the multiple expansion you are asking for.

The reason it is not working is that either the documentation is incorrect or there is a bug in Grafana (tested with version v6.7.2). From my tests, I suspect, the Prometheus expansion doesn't expand with the enclosing `()` and you end up with the expression `=~"127\.0\.0\.1|127\.0\.0\.2:10250"` - which is not what you want.

The workaround is to use the regex notation `=~"${ip_test:regex}:10250"`.